# Angular Js combine different entries with the same category of JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
[{"Category":"cat","Value":"large cat"},
{"Category":"cat","Value":"small cat"},
{"Category":"dog","Value":"large dog"},
{"Category":"dog","Value":"little dog"},
{"Category":"dog","Value":"cute dog"}]
```

If I have a json file like this, how can I display them with angular js to the same category like below?

```
cat 
large cat
small cat
dog
large dog
little dog
cute dog
```

I tried to search for the answer but most of them are trying to remove the duplicate entries instead of combining them into same category.
I used ng-repeat and an unique filter algorithm that is provided by [this link](https://tutorialedge.net/post/javascript/angularjs/removing-duplicates-from-ng-repeat/). 

Could you please tell me how to do that?

The code below is what I currently use.

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals | unique : 'Category'">
        <div>{{animal.Category}}</div>
        <div>{{animal.Value}}</div> 
</div>
```

This will give the result like

```
cat
large cat
dog
large dog
```

Sadly, this is not what I expect.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: This question is solved with the method that is given by CodeWarrior. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ic08D2IGJYexZuGscWDQ?p=preview)

Use the loop that you created with the unique filter to figure out the unique categories. And then use a nested loop to list out animals matching the category like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in animals | unique : 'Category'">
  <span style="font-weight: bold">{{category.Category}}</span>
  <div ng-repeat="animal in animals" ng-show="animal.Category === category.Category">
    {{animal.Value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! This is super cool. Simple but effective! Really appreciate! It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the desired outcome.

```js
let data = [{
    category: "cat",
    value: "large cat"
}, {
    category: "cat",
    value: "small cat"
}, {
    category: "dog",
    value: "large dog"
}, {
    category: "dog",
    value: "small dog"
}, {
    category: "dog",
    value: "cute dog"
}, {
    category: "turtle",
    value: "water turtle"
}, {
    category: "turtle",
    value: "land turtle"
}];

let grouped = data.reduce((out, item) => {
    out[item.category] = out[item.category] || [];
    out[item.category].push(item.value);

    return out;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);

let categories = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => ({key, values: grouped[key]}));

console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **groupby** filter

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals  |  groupBy:'Category'" >
<h2 ng-show="animals[$index - 1].Category !=animal.Category">{{item.Category }}</h2>
<ul>
    <li>{{animal.Value}}</li>
</ul>
```